# Performing multiple requests Axios (Vue.js)

Tags: http, vuejs2, vue.js, axios

I am trying to perform two, non-concurrent request, but would like to use data from my first request before performing a second request.  How can I achieve getting the data from the first request then using that data for the second request?

```js
axios.get('/user/12345').then(response => this.arrayOne = response.data);
axios.get('/user/12345/' + this.arrayOne.name + '/permissions').then(response => this.arrayTwo = response.data);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just nest the second `axios` call inside the first one.

```js
axios.get('/user/12345').then(response => {
   this.arrayOne = response.data
   axios.get('/user/12345/' + this.arrayOne.name + '/permissions').then(
       response => this.arrayTwo = response.data
     );
  });
```

Comment: Even though this works, when you have many axios calls this gets messy. The answer using async/await by Nicholas Kajoh is much simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use **async/await** in **ES2017**:

```
myFunction = async () => {
  const response1 = await axios.get('/user/12345');
  this.arrayOne = response1.data;
  const response2 = await axios.get(`/user/12345/${this.arrayOne.name}/permissions`);
  this.arrayTwo = response2.data;
}
myFunction().catch(e => console.log(e));
```

OR

```
myFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const response1 = await axios.get('/user/12345');
    this.arrayOne = response1.data;
    const response2 = await axios.get(`/user/12345/${this.arrayOne.name}/permissions`);
    this.arrayTwo = response2.data;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this helps me more than the selected answer